# Variable in static block is static or not

Tags: java

```
class A{
    public static int foo = 20;
}

class B extends A{
    public static int foo = 30;
    static {
    int foo = 40;
    }
}
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args){
         B b = new B();
         System.out.println(b.foo);
         System.out.println(B.foo);
}
```

O/P : 30
30 
I Know that static blocked is initialized first during class loading time and they are initialized from top to bottom.First foo in A class will be identified then foo in B class will be identified and then finally foo in static block will be identified.Now foo in A will be initialized to 20 and now foo becomes 30 in child class B and finally foo in static block will be initialized to 40 .So my question is why o/p is not 40 because lastly foo has value 40. Is foo from A to B class is inherited or do both class share foo as having same variable. And foo in static block is different or same. I am newbie so kindly make my concept correctly

Comment: Neither. A variable *declared* in a static block is a **local** variable, meaning it is visible only within the block of declaration, and so is neither a static nor an instance field.

Comment: The three `foo` have absolutely nothing to do with each other, they only have the same name. Change their names around to see what `b.foo` and `B.foo` actually refer to.

Comment: I suggest reading about variables scope, or variables/fields in general

Comment: It's a static _initialization_ block. Initialization occurs after class loading, not during it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access fist variable as `A.foo`. Second - `B.foo`. Third will dissapear after end of static block.

Comment: i have B.foo and also a foo in static block so these two variable with same name points to same or diff location in memory

Comment: in Java location in memory is hidden, so you cannot manage it from your program. To change your `A.foo` ore `B.foo` in staticblock - you should write `static {A.foo = 55; B.foo = 125;}` When you write `static {int foo = 40;}` the word `int` means that you declare NEW variable.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not 40 because in the static block you are not assigning a new value to the `foo` variable,
but you are defining a different variable (which has nothing to do with `foo` from A and B classes). 
If you would do this:

```
static {
     foo = 40;
    }
```

than the output would be 40

The thing that is going on between `foo` from A class and `foo` from B class is called 'hiding variable'.
It's when you in the child class define a variable with the same name as a variable in a parent class.
(but it's considered as a poor coding practice as it makes the code very confusing)

Comment: foo in static block without int specifier is shared or not between parent and child class

Comment: no, it's not shared. when you write `foo = 40` in the static block you are just assigning this new value to the `foo` variable of the B class. `foo`  of the A class remains 20.